# Is there a way to modify an fxml file through the code itself?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

What I need is basically to modify a .fxml file via code with some parameters I'm getting from a .json, let's say a method that changes the values in the file itself. Ex:

```
void modifyFile(){
    fxml file atribute = new value;
}
```

Comment: Please read the Code of conduct before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the look and feel of the content you can create/modify the content on the fly once you get your data as opposed to modifying the fxml file. This is an example that may help:  https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

Comment: I believe this is a [YX problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) I find no reason to edit the fxml file, unless if you are creating an app like scenebuilder which (in your case) would (probably) display and edit at the same time a FXML file. Now in case you want to know how to interact with a fxml file you should check about "controllers" a quick google search will give you tons of post for example : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/fxml.html

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'm kind of new to java as a whole. I thought that, because I'm using scene builder, I had to edit the interface through the app itself.

Comment: @IvanSolid Welcome then, no you don't need to edit the fxml. Instead you will associate a controller  (which is a java class) to your FXML and then manipulate your controls and their data from there.